# Swagger configuration - 404 when accessing swagger.json

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, swagger

I'm new to swagger and looking to get it set up on my latest REST API project but am failing miserably. Everything seems to be configured correctly but I am unable to navigate to swagger.json without getting a 404. I can't see what is missing or wrong

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exclusions as the project uses version 1.11.1 and causes conflicts if 1.13 is imported from swagger

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            io.swagger.jaxrs.json,
            io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
            uk.package.test.myproject
        </param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8082/myproject/api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Example annotations...

```
@ManagedBean
@Path("secure/cache")
@Restrict("ManageCache")
@Api(value = "secure/cache", description = "Rest api for do operations on     admin", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AdminApi {....


@GET
@Path("{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

@ApiOperation(value = "Get specific admin", httpMethod = "GET", notes = "Fetch the admin user details", response = Response.class)
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Given admin user found"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Given admin user not found"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error due to encoding the data"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request due to decoding the data"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "Pre condition failed due to required data not found") })

public List<String> getCacheKeys(.....
```

When the project is run the following is logged...

```
10:46:48,724 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  io.swagger.jaxrs.json
  io.swagger.jaxrs.listing
  uk.package.test.myproject
10:46:48,771 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) Root resource classes found:
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.NotificationApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.UserApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.FlagsApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.UnitsByFunctionApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.CvDataApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.ImageApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.GazetteerApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.SearchApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.ViewApi
  class uk.package.test.myproject.api.AdminApi
10:46:48,776 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) No provider classes found.
10:46:48,834 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer] (MSC service thread 1-5) CDI support is enabled
10:46:48,842 INFO  [com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-5) Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
```

Thank you in advance

Cheers

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I have resolved this by using a custom Application rather than using package scanning :)

Thanks for your help

Martin

Comment: Can you share your solution? Because I'm using a custom `Application` too (coming from my `Jersey` configuration), but I can't see the docs nor any error anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet mapping says that you should not be looking at the path you specified:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That typically means to look under the /api path.  That means then, unless you're using a webapp called myproject, you should be looking under /api/swagger.json